# Live out – usage and meaning

Tags: phrasal-verbs

This is no way to **live out** your twenties.

The meaning I'm going for here is "go through and was wondering if this was an alright usage of the phrasal verb **live out**.

Comment: Not to this native English speaker. I would possibly guess the intended meaning, but it would only be a guess.

Answer (score 1):

The idiom “live out” is usually used in reference to the end of life.

> After her husband died, she lived out the rest of her life in a nursing home.

It seems a bit strange to apply to someone who is not yet thirty.